# jQuery like image swap in YUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui

Im trying to replicate a simple hover effect in YUI just like you would with jQuery however its a little confusing.
As in jquery it would go:

```
$('.hoverclass').hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass('up');
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('up');
});
```

Any pointers how to do it in YUI?

Thanks.

Comment: jugger you should mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you even need JS for this. Can't you just use CSS for this?

Well anyway check the source for this sample from Edwart Visser

[YUI Hover](http://www.lutsr.nl/yui/hover/)

The JS which is most of interest to you

[YUI Hover JS](http://www.lutsr.nl/yui/hover/script.js) (there is some other code in it for yui module detecion, skip to this comment `/* HOVER CODE */`)

Comment: Thanks alot, Ill have a look into it.

Unfortunately I do need to use JS, I want hover effects on input boxes - fine except in IE6.